# Cannot sort array a second time

Tags: c, function, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am not able to sort the numbers after second loop, the first group numbers get sorted but after that they just print the given numbers in same order.
Ex-input:

```
2                                                          
4

67
90
76
89

3

67
45
12
```

output:

```
67 76 89 90 

67 45 12
```

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define Read(inp) scanf("%i",&inp)
#define For(i,a) for(i=0; i<a; i++)

int temp;

void sort(int num1, int num2, int inp2[][num1]);

int main() {
  int T;

  int N[100];
  int weight[100][100];
  int i, j;
  Read(T);

  For(i,T)
  {
    Read(N[i]);
    For(j,N[i])
    {
      Read(weight[i][j]);
    }
  }

  int e, d;
  For(e,T)
  {
    sort(N[e], e, weight);
    For(d,N[e])
    {
      printf("%i ", weight[e][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void sort(int num1, int num2, int inp2[][num1]) {
  int d, e;
  For(d,num1-1)
  {
    For(e,num1-1-d)
    {
      if (inp2[num2][e] > inp2[num2][e + 1]) {
        temp = inp2[num2][e];
        inp2[num2][e] = inp2[num2][e + 1];
        inp2[num2][e + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Using macros as a lazy way to write code, along with the atrocious code formatting, makes your new language practically unreadable. Can you supply a manual please?

Comment: rewrite this code without macroses

Comment: `void sort(int num1,int num2,int inp2[][num1]);` --> `void sort(int num1,int num2,int inp2[][100]);` Because `weight` isn't VLA.

Comment: thanks @BLUEPIXY changing that part works.

Comment: Curious: Are the `Read(inp) For(i,a)` macro ideas yours,  one you read or was taught?

Comment: @chux no,I have seen these in a code written by someone else.

Comment: @A.S.H please enlarge. This is a C question.

Comment: @A.S.H Perhaps C programmers are not of the same laziness as C++ ones?  New ideas (good and bad) come slowly to C.  -  Code base inertia.

Comment: @A.S.H as a "tried-but-forget" (for reasons I do not care to expound on) non-C++ writer I have no idea what you mean or what relevance that has.

Comment: @chux and WV seriously I sometimes wonder why there are so many features in the "new" C++ std that are no more than "shortcuts". Anyway, I might be missing the final goal...

Comment: The global variable `temp` is a bad idea.  It should be local to the swap block of code in the `sort()` function.  Give variables the minimum scope possible.  Compared with some of the other problems, maybe that's not to serious, but it is something to watch in general.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for suggestion I will look after it next time,it always good to think about the other scopes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: You should write up your comment as an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: this is silly mistake. I suggest that `sort(int n, int array[n]);` call `sort(N[e], weight[e]);`